# Specify multiple environments in Intern w/ Browserstack

Tags: functional-testing, intern, browserstack

I am trying to run parallel functional tests on BrowserStack using Intern.  My current working intern.json config looks like this:

```
{
  "proxyPort": 9000,

  "capabilities": {
    "browserstack.local": false,
    "browserstack.debug": true,
    "browserstack.video": true,
    "fixSessionCapabilities": false
  },

  "environments": [
    { "browserName": "Chrome",  "version": 62  },
    { "browserName": "Firefox", "version": 38  },
    { "browserName": "Safari",  "version": 9   },
    { "browserName": "IE",      "version": 11  }
  ],

  "tunnel": "browserstack",

  "tunnelOptions": {
      "username": "myUsername",
      "accessKey": "myAccessKey"
  },

  "reporters": ["pretty"],
  "functionalSuites": ["dist/functional/tests/demo.js"]
}
```

However, my tests won't run when I try to specify an OS, os_version, or anything else inside of each environments object, like this:

```
{ "browserName": "Chrome",  "version": 62, "os" : "OS X" },
```

I have been referring to the BrowserStack docs:  https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities

Additionally, I am unable to specify any mobile device within this configuration - it yells that its missing a browserName property...

Any idea to how to do either of the above?  Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working sample for your configuration:

```
    define({
  proxyPort: 9000,

  capabilities: {
    'browserstack.local': false,
    fixSessionCapabilities: false
  },

  defaultTimeout: 300000,

  environments: [
      { browser: 'Chrome',  'browser_version': '62','os': 'Windows','os_version': '7'  },
        { browser: 'Firefox', 'browser_version': '38'  },
        { browser: 'Safari','browser_version': '9'   },
        { browser: 'IE',  'browser_version': '11'  },

        // This will ONLY work on real_mobile supported devices
        { browser: 'Safari', 'device': 'iPhone X', 'real_mobile': 'true'  },
        // This will work as an emulated mobile device
        {"browser": "android", "device": "Google Nexus 7", "os_version": "4.1"}

  ],

  maxConcurrency: 3,

  tunnel: 'BrowserStackTunnel',

  tunnelOptions: {
    verbose: true,
     username: '<Username>',
     accessKey: '<AccessKey>'
  },

  reporters: [ 'Pretty' ],

  loaderOptions: {
    packages: null
  },

  suites: null,

  functionalSuites: [ 'tests/single_test' ],

  excludeInstrumentation: true
});
```

The above demonstrates env configuration for a real_mobile supported device and an emulated mobile device.

List of all devices supported by BrowserStack Automate can be found here: https://www.browserstack.com/list-of-browsers-and-platforms?product=automate. Devices marked with blue icon are real mobile devices and not available as emulators.

Comment: I do not have a realMobile plan, this solution gives the error:  "You can upgrade to the Automate Mobile plan to test on real devices. Please reach out to our Sales team at sales@browserstack.com.
".  If I turn real_mobile to false, I get this error: " Could not find device: iPhone X"

Comment: If you have access to emulators, you may use iPhone 6 without the realMobile capability. If you do not have access to emulators, you will need to reach out to their support for alternate solutions

Comment: Access to the emulators?  I would assume BrowserStack would default to using emulators if realMobile was false - I haven't seen any documentation that indicates otherwise.

Comment: based on their documentation, devices here are available for testing: https://www.browserstack.com/list-of-browsers-and-platforms?product=automate and device with blue mark are real and not available as emulators

Comment: Thanks BountyHunter - I reached out to BrowserStack - and they confirmed this as well - I'll edit the example above to accommodate to both ways (a supported mobile device vs. emulator supported)

Answer (score 0):

2. It seems not every os_version BrowserStack listed in their capacities works. But I tried the config below and it worked!

   `{ browser: "Chrome", version: "62", os: "OS X", os_version: "El Capitan" }`

This one should work as well:

```
{ browser: "Chrome", version: "62", os: "OS X"}
```

3. To run in mobile devices: I don't work with mobile devices, so I am not so sure, but I think it's good to get the correct name for device, os_version.. (you'd better to ask BrowserStack directly)
   But I tried and this one worked for me:

   `{browser: "android", device: "Google Nexus 7", os_version: "4.1"}`

Comment: For #1, changing the tunnel to "BrowserStackTunnel" yields this error: "error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.".  When I set tunnel to "browserstack" - it works and I can see all of my tests run on BrowserStack.

Comment: For #3, that mobile device did work!  Strange - many of them haven't worked, I am still waiting to hear back from BrowserStack for clarification around this.

Comment: For #1: Sorry, I updated my answer. You use intern 4 (while I'm still using 3 :D )

Comment: For #2, #3: I saw the same things - not every environment in BrowserStack's list works. But because I just need to run tests in certain environments, so I didn't bother to ask